# Cannot instance a View Model because the table is empty

Tags: java, android, android-room, viewmodel

I'm creating a view model in my activity in order to add an object to the database via method. But the view model is representing an empty table, and it's causing this stack trace and complete crash of the application:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gmproxy.pastilarma, PID: 9827
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gmproxy.pastilarma/com.gmproxy.pastilarma.UserAddScreen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.gmproxy.Util.PathologyUserViewModel
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.gmproxy.Util.PathologyUserViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at com.gmproxy.pastilarma.UserAddScreen.onCreate(UserAddScreen.java:84)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
    at com.gmproxy.pastilarma.UserAddScreen.onCreate(UserAddScreen.java:84) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:385)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:441)
    at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
    at com.gmproxy.DAO.PathologyUserDAO_Impl.getAllObjects(PathologyUserDAO_Impl.java:154)
    at com.gmproxy.DAO.PathologyUserRepository.getAllObjects(PathologyUserRepository.java:19)
    at com.gmproxy.Util.PathologyUserViewModel.<init>(PathologyUserViewModel.java:19)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
    at com.gmproxy.pastilarma.UserAddScreen.onCreate(UserAddScreen.java:84) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

This is happening as soon as I enter said activity. The other view models that have records in the database are created with no problem, but the other ones that lack any object in the database fail to create too. Do I purposedly need to add a record in order to create those?

This is the activity and view model code respectively:

Activity:

```
package com.gmproxy.pastilarma;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.gmproxy.DAO.PathologyUserDAO;
import com.gmproxy.DAO.UserDAO;
import com.gmproxy.Entities.Pathology;
import com.gmproxy.Entities.User;
import com.gmproxy.Util.AlarmUserViewModel;
import com.gmproxy.Util.ImageConverter;
import com.gmproxy.Util.PathologyUserViewModel;
import com.gmproxy.Util.UserViewModel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserAddScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button gotoBack, addObservation, saveUser, addPathologies;
    EditText addUsername, addSurname, addAge, addRoomNumber;
    Spinner addGender;
    ImageView selectImage;
    String obs;
    Pathology paths;
    Context context;
    UserViewModel userViewModel;
    PathologyUserViewModel pathologyUserViewModel;
    int pathAct = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        context = this.getApplicationContext();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        pathAct = getIntent().getIntExtra("path-record",0);
        if (pathAct == 1){
            onRestoreInstanceState(bundle);
        }


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_add_screen);
        gotoBack = findViewById(R.id.GotoBack);
        addObservation = findViewById(R.id.AddObservation);
        saveUser = findViewById(R.id.SaveUser);
        addPathologies = findViewById(R.id.AddPathologies);
        addUsername = findViewById(R.id.AddUsername);
        addSurname = findViewById(R.id.AddSurname);
        addAge = findViewById(R.id.AddAge);
        addRoomNumber = findViewById(R.id.AddRoomNumber);
        addGender = findViewById(R.id.AddGender);
        selectImage = findViewById(R.id.SelectImage);

        userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
        pathologyUserViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PathologyUserViewModel.class);

        List<String> genderList = new ArrayList<>();
        genderList.add("M");
        genderList.add("F");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,genderList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        addGender.setAdapter(adapter);


        obs = intent.getStringExtra("observation");
        paths = (Pathology) intent.getSerializableExtra("paths");
    }

    public void gotoBack(View view) {
        Intent mainAct = new Intent(UserAddScreen.this, UserListScreen.class);
        startActivity(mainAct);
    }

    public void addObservation(View view) {
        Intent mainAct = new Intent(UserAddScreen.this, UserObservationScreen.class);
        startActivity(mainAct);

    }

    public void addPathology(View view) {
        Intent mainAct = new Intent(UserAddScreen.this, PathologiesSearchScreen.class);
        startActivity(mainAct);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putString("Nombre_usuario",addUsername.getText().toString());
        savedInstanceState.putString("Apellido_usuario",addSurname.getText().toString());
        savedInstanceState.putString("Edad_usuario",addAge.getText().toString());
        savedInstanceState.putString("Habitacion_usuario",addRoomNumber.getText().toString());
        savedInstanceState.putInt("Sexo_usuario",addGender.getSelectedItemPosition());
        savedInstanceState.putString("Observacion-usuario", obs);
        savedInstanceState.putSerializable("Patologia-usuario", paths);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        addUsername.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("Nombre_usuario"));
        addSurname.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("Apellido_usuario"));
        addAge.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("Edad_usuario"));
        addRoomNumber.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("Habitacion_usuario"));
        addGender.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("Sexo_usuario"));
        obs = savedInstanceState.getString("Observacion-usuario");
        paths = (Pathology) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Patologia-usuario");

    }

    public void selectImageAction(View view) {
        final CharSequence[] options = {"Hacer una foto", "Elegir de la galería", "Usar una genérica" , "Cancelar"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserAddScreen.this);
        builder.setTitle("¡Añade una foto!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Hacer una foto")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Elegir de la galería")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancelar")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } else if(options[item].equals("Usar una genérica")){
                    selectImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_user_generic_foreground);
                    selectImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_user_generic_foreground);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);
                    selectImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("..******************...", picturePath + "");
                ImageView viewImage;
                selectImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        }
    }




    public void saveUser(View view) {

        //Just this to turn the image into a blob

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.id.SelectImage);
        ImageConverter imgCon = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] bytearray = imgCon.bitmapToBiteArray(bitmap);


        Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario creado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        User user = new User(addUsername.getText().toString(), addSurname.getText().toString(), addAge.getText().toString(),
                Integer.parseInt(addRoomNumber.getText().toString()), addGender.getSelectedItem().toString(), obs, bytearray);
        userViewModel.insert(user);
        pathologyUserViewModel.insert(userViewModel.getIdByNameAndSurname(addUsername.getText().toString(),addSurname.getText().toString()), paths.getId_pathology());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Patología " + paths.getPathologyName() + " añadida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent mainAct = new Intent(UserAddScreen.this, UserListScreen.class);
        startActivity(mainAct);
        finish();
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
package com.gmproxy.Util;

import android.app.Application;

import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;

import com.gmproxy.DAO.PathologyUserRepository;
import com.gmproxy.Entities.PathologyUser;

import java.util.List;

public class PathologyUserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
        private PathologyUserRepository repository;
        public List<PathologyUser> pathologyUsers;

        public PathologyUserViewModel(Application application) {
                super(application);
                repository = new PathologyUserRepository(application);
                pathologyUsers = repository.getAllObjects();
        }

        List<PathologyUser> getAll() { return pathologyUsers; }

        public List<PathologyUser> getAllFromUser(int i) { return repository.getAllFromUser(i); }

        public void insert(int i, int j) { repository.insertObject(i,j); }

        public void delete(PathologyUser obj) { repository.deleteObject(obj); }
}
```

I don't quite remember anything about not being able to create view models with empty tables in the documentation, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Your crash says the error is in `com.gmproxy.pastilarma.UserAddScreen.onRestoreInstanceState(UserAddScreen.java:125)`; that has nothing to do with your ViewModel. Can you include your `UserAddScreen`?

Comment: It's the activity that's coded up there, over the view model. And yeah, forgot one quite important thing, will fix it right now, give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the line:

```
pathologyUserViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PathologyUserViewModel.class);
```

You can use:

```
pathologyUserViewModel = new ViewModelProvider
        .AndroidViewModelFactory(this.getApplication())
        .create(PathologyUserViewModel.class);
```

Or,

```
pathologyUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application)
        ).get(PathologyUserViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: I am afraid that the code you provided doesn't stop the program from getting the same errors and crash

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the log, you are trying to access the database on the main thread :-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time
```

at the line :-

```
pathologyUsers = repository.getAllObjects();
```

You either need to run this on another thread OR alternately (and not recommended) allow it to run on the main thread which can be done by using:-

```
.allowMainThreadQueries()
```

when building the room database. e.g. :-

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, TheDatabase::class.java, "thedatabasefile.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() //<<<<<<<<<< allow main thread run
                    .build()
```

> Do I purposedly need to add a record in order to create those?

As long as you are handling the returned Lists correctly and not assuming they are not empty, there should be no problem.

Comment: How could I work with them in order to assume that they can be empty?

Comment: @Cpt-Proxy it's more don't do anything that assumes they are not empty e.g. don't try to access element n directly rather check there are elements e.g. use `if (list.size() >= n) ....`. i.e. you probably have to do nothing special (that you wouldn't do).